# Jasper Report not working in Liferay 6.2

Tags: java, maven, report

I'm using Liferay 6.2, tomcat 7, Maven and Java of course.
I'm trying to create report using Jesper Report, but my code displaying something weird like this :

```
%PDF-1.4 %âãÏÓ 3 0 obj <>stream x½ÔMKÃ0Àñ{>EóP}ò¤¯ÇNô u0(x)£íÆ¤ë´k~{\Ñ'B2Ø o¿fùó¼³uÉdÌSyÙ°»mòuTp?ê; 'vs/¸^îÙêª|U×~]¼>}¿ ÇY|ÿ¸ôéáÀVõy.íx»V=øá>¿Ì¿~¡¿) .. etc
```

There's something wrong with my code ?

*report.jsp*

```
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*"%>
<%@page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@ page contentType="application/pdf" %>
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
<%
        try{
            List<Map<String,?>> dataSource = (List<Map<String,?>>) request.getAttribute("listCoursePlan");
            JRDataSource jrds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataSource);
            String jrxmlFile = session.getServletContext().getRealPath("/report/report.jrxml"); 

            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(jrxmlFile));

            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(input);
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null,jrds);
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, response.getOutputStream());
            response.getOutputStream().flush();
            response.getOutputStream().close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
%>
```

JavaController :

```
@RenderMapping(params = "action=renderExport")
    public String renderExport(RenderRequest request,RenderResponse response,Model model) throws Exception{
Report report = new Report();
List<Map<String, ?>> values = report.coursePlan("ABC001",9);
model.addAttribute("listCoursePlan", values);.
return "report";    
}
```

*report.java*

```
public class Report {
    public List<Map <String,?>> coursePlan(String studentid, Integer cluid) throws Exception{
        List<Map<String,?>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String,?>>();
        CoursePlanDao planDao = new CoursePlanDao();
        for(CoursePlan v : planDao.getCourse(studentid,cluid)){
            Map<String,Object> m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            m.put("coursetitle", v.getCoursetitle());
            m.put("code", v.getCode());
            m.put("student_grade", v.getStudent_grade());
            m.put("credit", v.getCredit());
            m.put("course_type", v.getCourse_type());
            m.put("score", v.getScore());
            m.put("grade_fin", v.getGrade_fin());
            list.add(m);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

[image]
Can anyone help me to resolve this ?

Comment: You have to use a resource method ti serve the generated pdf using a jsp you are loading all the portal and all the other jsp